# JPA persist a new entity with or without a set id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA to persist entities to my database. The Id column is represented by the Persistable class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Persistable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "CustomGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name="CustomGenerator", strategy = "parohia.imported.domain.UseExistingOrGenerateIdGenerator")
Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

My custom generator is this:

```
public class UseExistingOrGenerateIdGenerator extends IdentityGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object)
            .getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
    return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object);
}
```

}

My goal is to persist entities which have an id using that id and entities which do not have an id with a generated id. Is this possible?

```
 EntityManager entityManager = databaseService.getEntityManager();
 entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
 entityManager.persist(new Persoana(5000L,"test","test"));
 entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
 entityManager.close();
```

When persisting an entity with no set id everything works fine. But when an id is set I get

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist

Comment: Persisting changes you would need to use `.merge()` instead of `.persist()`

Comment: My guess: despite your custom generator, the entity is marked as having a generated ID. When you send an entity with a filled Id field the JPA Entity Manager considers that this entity already exists, because the Id should be generated. Also you should consider that even if your code worked the approach could be error prone, since the automatic generation could give a number already used in a "manual" creation.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct and using .merge() seems to do the trick. @VitorSantos your point is also valid. Do you any solution besides a graceful error handling at run-time when detecting a duplicate id?

Comment: @PetruScurtu , for checking duplicates I usually write a query to check if there are duplicates already in the DB, then I throw a business exception or perform any other error handling. I tend to not trust on catching runtime exceptions to implement business rules. If doing the extra query is a real problem then go for the error handling route.